# Quantum solitons: derivation of $ \int {\phi^\prime}^2 dx = M$ using Lorentz invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, classical-field-theory, solitons

I was reading through page 10 of [this document](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/3P11e.pdf) (Chua, 2017) on quantum solitons, and came across the following statement relating to the equation for kinetic energy

$$T = \left(\frac{da}{dt}\right)^2\int\frac{1}{2}{\phi^\prime}^2 dx = \frac{1}{2}M\left(\frac{da}{dt}\right)^2$$

> "We can derive this result from Lorentz invariance to see that the
>   result of integration is manifestly $M$."

My question is simply how do we derive this result using the method described above? I can't understand how we have arrived at the equation above (in particular, where does the mass $M$ come from?)

Any help is much appreciated.